# Unity ML Agents Package Manager is not importing Actuator script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I want to test  the Unity ML example "3D Ball". So, I set up environment:

1. Imported the ML Agents Package by Unity Package Manager.
2. Copied the ML Agent example Assets from Unity's official GitHub to My Project File.

Then, I opened the example scene and played that scene. But every code which contains "using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators" fails with the following error:

> Assets\test.cs(5,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Actuators' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity.MLAgents' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So, I've tried to find MLAgents.Actuator module's source code. But I didn't find anything yet.

Someone said Actuator Module is applied after ML Agent 1.0.3, but I imported the lasted version (v. 1.0.4).

How can I import the ML Agents package properly? Every YouTube tutorial does not show the problem I've encountered.

Here is my environment:

- Unity version: Unity 2020.1.0f
- ML Agents version: version 1.0.4
- ML Agents example: version Release 7

Comment: Actuators are a new feature that were added in 1.4.0-preview. They don't exist in any of the 1.0.x packages.

Comment: If you need to use the 1.0.x pacakage, make sure you're getting the examples from a compatible version (not the master branch). For example, here's the 1.0.2 tag: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/tree/com.unity.ml-agents_1.0.2. Looks like 1.03 and 1.0.4 tags are missing but I'll update them tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.:) I'll try that advise.

Answer (score 1):

Update the package to a `1.4.0-preview` or later (depending on your Unity version, you may need to change some package manager settings to be able to see preview packages).
Get the examples from a tag that corresponds to the `1.0.x` package, for example `com.unity.ml-agents_1.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually install it from the repository you cloned.

Answer (score 0):

I added the project from "Unity Hub" rather than inserting asset folder to a new project.
And then everything works fine. Even the preview packages like
[com.unity.ml-agents.extensions": "file:../../com.unity.ml-agents.extensions]
added automatically to the project from my project directory!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the 1.0.x pacakage, make sure you're getting the examples from a compatible version (not the master branch). For example, here's the 1.0.2 tag: github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/tree/…. Looks like 1.03 and 1.0.4 tags are missing but I'll update them tomorrow. – celion Sep 27 '20 at 20:27

Celion had the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I am very new to Unity. I figured out it is something with the versioning. You need to use the proper version of the package. By installing from the Unity Registry, I was not able to install the last version.

I just install the package from the Disk. [Here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/main/docs/Installation.md#install-the-comunityml-agents-unity-package) follow the **Install the com.unity.ml-agents Unity package**. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Unity.MLAgents.Actuators** this package is in preview till this date, if you want to use this package you need to update your MLAgents package from package manager.