# Unity's ml-agents assets throw warnings and errors [PushBlockWithInput, Actuator, Barracuda]

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

### The Problem

I'm trying to work with [Unity Machine Learning Agents](https://unity.com/products/machine-learning-agents) and encountered problems during the setup. When I try to import the assets from [Unity's ml-agents git](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents) into Unity, I get many warnings and errors inside Unity. For the purpose of context, I'm at the very beginning of learning Unity, so I don't know if the errors are due to the ml-agents package or user error from my side in how to set everything up.

### The errors and warnings

Instructions to create a first test scene with assets from Unity's ml-agents git suggest making a new 3D project in Unity and drag and drop the folder `projects/assets/ml-agents` into the project's assets. At this point, Unity is showing many errors and warnings in the Terminal. It still has the examples in the assets but every element in the scene is full of warnings.

according to these tutorials from 2020 by dragging and dropping the assets into Unity [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhS6-vvhOy8&t=469s) [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9aPZH6pyA8&t=86s), I subsequently
[image]

In my case the majority of the warnings seem to come from `PushBlockWithInput`, `PushblockActions` and `PushBlockWithInputPlayerController` missing `UnityEngine.InputSystem` and `Unity.MLAgents.Extensions.Input` with the note "(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". This; however, did not happen in the aforementioned tutorials.

Although they make the majority of errors, they are not exclusively about assembly references. Other errors, which may or may not be about assembly references, are

- error CS0115: 'Match3Board.GetCurrentBoardSize()': no suitable method found to override
- error CS0535: 'SensorBase' does not implement interface member 'ISensor.GetCompressionType()'

[image]

### The things I've tried

#### Python

I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/main/docs/Installation.md) from Unity's ml-agents git and was successful in installing a Python 3.7 environment with Anaconda, PyTorch with Cuda, and the Unity's ml-agents python package via pip. When trying to verify the ml-agents python package works with `mlagents-learn --help`, I first got an exception but could resolve that by updating `protobuf==3.20.1` as per [suggestion from a forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly/25639/3) (just mentioning this in case it is relevant).

#### Unity

I downloaded the C# package from Unity's package manager and tried it for several versions (`1.0.8 (Verified), 1.9.1 (Preview), 2.0.1, and 2.1.0 (Preview) -- lastest`). After which I'm able to select ML-Agents from the 'Add Component' menu in the Inspector.

I've also tried to create a new Unity project with the `ml-agent package 1.9.1 (Preview)` with the right Barracuda version, and the release 19 branch of Unity's ml-agents git, without success (now it's 53 warnings and 70 errors). Now also the Actuators are not found, which seems to be a more common problem on its own.

#### VS Code

I'm using VS Code as opposed to VS as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301180/2451456). I downloaded .Net version 6.0.301 and checked it was installed with 'dotnet --info'. In the VS Code's extension manager, I installed the extensions [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp), [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), [Unity Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobiah.unity-tools)
, [Debugger for Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug).

#### Git-Repository

I have also switched from Unity's ml-agents git's main branch to the [release 19 branch](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/tree/release_19_branch) and also tried other versions of the Barracuda package, e.g. `Version 3.0.0`, which seems to remove the warnings, but not the errors and instead gives these notifications:

[image]

However, warnings still show up in the assets' settings:

[image]

### Course: ML-Agents: Hummingbirds

I successfully completed the [ML-Agents: Hummingbirds](https://learn.unity.com/course/ml-agents-hummingbirds?uv=2019.3). This course doesn't use any of the assets from the ML-agents Git repository. Although, assets for this course are downloaded and added the same way, without issues. This lets me assume that the general setup for ML-agents is working but I specifically can't import the assets.

### My setup

- I'm working on a machine with Windows 11
- `Unity Version is 2020.3.32f1 Personal <DX11>`
- The Unity `ml-agent package` was tried with `1.0.8 (Verified), 1.9.1 (Preview), 2.0.1, and 2.0.2 (Preview)`
- The Unity `ML Agents Extensions` package 0.6.1 (preview)
- Python Version is, as per [instructions](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/main/docs/Installation.md), `3.7 with an Anaconda virtual environment`
- Unity's ml-agents git is `main`, as well as `release_19_branch`
- C# editor would be `Visual Studio Code 1.67.2`
- DotNet Version: 6.0.301

### Things I found out so far

This problem seems to be somewhat common, I've found several variations of similar problems over a couple of years, some more specific to the [Actuators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085348/unity-ml-agents-package-manager-is-not-importing-actuator-script) missing, some more [general](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/issues/3027). Some are posting about [problems with the InputSystem](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-find-unityengine-inputsystem.807645/) as well, but seemingly different solutions and mixed reactions to the solutions.

There are various suggestions, about version changes for Unity, the ml-agents package, and Visual Studio Code. Other solutions involve downloading additional packages in Visual Studio or Unity. Some suggest editing scripts within the cloned git repository. Although most of these threads are from the past 2 years. I've spent two days trying to set this up and fix this and am just about to give up on the ml-agents package. A shame the installation process for a seemingly great resource seems so infeasible. I'd appreciate further suggestions or directions on additional resources on how to set up this package.

Comment: Sometimes the input system in my unit looks like this. Sometimes cinemachine does the same. I reimport all and then it works. Unfortunately, I do not know the reason.

Comment: Have to tried to regenerate the project files in Unity Preferences > External Tools?

Comment: @DavidSdot Yes, I tried the 'Reset Argument' with the 'Generate all .csproj files' enabled, I have also tried to create a fresh project repeatedly, unfortunately with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the Input assembly definition(asmdef)
`Assets/Scripts` is where asmdef usually is but you cant just search it if it isn't there
[image]

In the Assembly Definition References section, click the + button to add a new reference and set it to `Unity.InputSystem`

[image]